# query from database php Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my database table there's a field called `city_case`, which accepts values such as `["3","4","5"]`. I can't query where the case is 3 or 5 or 4.

How can I select all data from this table where city_case = 3,4?

```html
function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->where('C.city_case',["4","5"]);
        return $this->db->get('cases C')->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `or_where`

```
function get_all()
{
    $this->db->where('C.city_case =', 4);
    $this->db->or_where('C.city_case =', 3); 
}


//Produces: WHERE C.city_case = 4 OR C.city_case = 3
```

Or in just normal query method

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbale_name WHERE C.city_case = 4 OR C.city_case = 3');
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you also try with where_in

```
function get_all()
{
    $arr= array('4', '5');
    $this->db->where_in('C.city_case',$arr);
    return $this->db->get('cases C')->result();
}
```